# Disable model validation for single .NET Core API action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an API controller for performing autosaves on an application I am developing. It uses the same viewmodel as the view, which has a number of required fields. The autosave controller may need to save a model that is not considered valid if the user has not completed the form when it is saved. By default, an .NET Core controller declared with the `[ApiController]` attribute will automatically force validation. I know I can disable this like so in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
     options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
});
```

But this will apply to all API controllers in the project. Is it possible to disable this default validation for only *one* controller or action? Everything I've found so far has directed me to use the code above, but that doesn't accomplish what I'm looking for.

Comment: You could add the `ModelBinder` attribute to the model, and make your own binder that does what you want.

Comment: Or don't pass any parameter to your action and extract the model values manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to approach this differently: Disabling the model validation will mean that there isn’t *any* validation for this action; not now, not later. Just because you do not require validation *right now* that doesn’t mean that you won’t need some kind of validation later on.

If you used some custom handling to disable the validation altogether for that action, then all you are doing is creating an actual exception into your application which will make it more complex. Developers looking at this later might not expect this behavior and could spend a good amount of time trying to figure out why the validation isn’t running when it’s working for every other action.

So instead, consider just duplicating the model so that each action has its own model: Action A has the original model with the validation attributes, requiring the values to be filled. And action B has a copy of that model without any validation attributes.

While this may seem wasteful, this does give you a few more benefits:

- If you later require validation for some fields on action B, you could just add some validation attributes back. You didn’t have to disable the automatic validation completely, so individual validation attributes will just continue to work if you add them to the model.
- Having separate models allows both actions to evolve independently. There’s already a good indicator that the actions do two different things: One requires the values, the other doesn’t. So it’s not unlikely that the models might need to diverge further in the future. For example, you might want to add a property to only one model but not the other.
- As already mentioned above, you can stick to the default behavior and keep a consistent development experience.

Comment: Thanks! That's a much cleaner solution for sure, although now I may need to add additional folders with my Models folder to keep them organized. I do still wonder if what I originally asked is possible, though.

Comment: In my case it's a whole class hierarchy which I will surely not duplicate, just because I want to be able to call one single method.

Answer (score 9):

Similar to Poke's answer, I would recommend using a different model for the action you want not to be validated. Instead of creating a copy of the model, however, I would just derive from the validated model and add the `[ValidateNever]` attribute, e.g.

```cs
[ValidateNever]
public class MyUnvalidatedModel : MyValidatedModel {
}
```

This will allow you to avoid a lot of duplication, while still giving you an unvalidated version of your model.

Answer (score 7):

You can override the default `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory`:

```
            services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory =
                    AllowingServerSideValidationToBeDisabledInvalidModelStateResponseFactoryHelper.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory;
            });
```

The `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory` below checks for `OptionalValidationAttribute` on a controller action, and searches for a form/query parameter flag which controls the validation is enabled/disabled:

```
    // Code taken from https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/5747cb36f2040d12e75c4b5b3f49580ef7aac5fa/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/DependencyInjection/ApiBehaviorOptionsSetup.cs#L23
    // and is modified to optionally disable validation for controller action methods decorated with OptionalValidationAttribute
    public static class AllowingServerSideValidationToBeDisabledInvalidModelStateResponseFactoryHelper
    {
        public static Func<ActionContext, IActionResult> InvalidModelStateResponseFactory => actionContext =>
        {
            var shouldEnableDataValidationarameterName = ((OptionalValidationAttribute)((ControllerActionDescriptor)actionContext.ActionDescriptor)
                .MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(OptionalValidationAttribute), true)
                .SingleOrDefault())?.ShouldEnableDataValidationParameterName;

            var isValidationEnabled = true;

            if (shouldEnableDataValidationarameterName != null)
            {
                var httpContextRequest = actionContext.HttpContext.Request;
                var shouldEnableDataValidationValue = httpContextRequest.Form[shouldEnableDataValidationarameterName]
                    .Union(httpContextRequest.Query[shouldEnableDataValidationarameterName]).FirstOrDefault();
                isValidationEnabled = shouldEnableDataValidationValue?.ToLower() == bool.TrueString.ToLower();
            }

            if (!isValidationEnabled)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var problemDetailsFactory = actionContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ProblemDetailsFactory>();
            var problemDetails = problemDetailsFactory.CreateValidationProblemDetails(actionContext.HttpContext, actionContext.ModelState);
            ObjectResult result;
            if (problemDetails.Status == 400)
            {
                // For compatibility with 2.x, continue producing BadRequestObjectResult instances if the status code is 400.
                result = new BadRequestObjectResult(problemDetails);
            }
            else
            {
                result = new ObjectResult(problemDetails)
                {
                    StatusCode = problemDetails.Status,
                };
            }
            result.ContentTypes.Add("application/problem+json");
            result.ContentTypes.Add("application/problem+xml");

            return result;
        };
    }
```

The `OptionalValidationAttribute`:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class OptionalValidationAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public OptionalValidationAttribute(string shouldEnableDataValidationParameterName)
        {
            ShouldEnableDataValidationParameterName = shouldEnableDataValidationParameterName;
        }

        public string ShouldEnableDataValidationParameterName { get; }
    }
```

Example usage on an controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
[OptionalValidation(shouldEnableDataValidationParameterName: nameof(shouldEnableDataValidation))] // C# 11 needed to use nameof for a method parameter 
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(
    [FromForm] int id,
    [FromForm] string name,
    [FromForm] bool shouldEnableDataValidation
)
{
...
}
```

Comment: solves perfectly... Sometimes one needs to do custom validation in the code when just the model validation doesn't fits... You helped in my situation. Thanks a lot

Comment: `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory => actionContext =>` this construct on your method signature line should be a red flag to you that using an expression bodied method here is hurting the readability of your code. Just because C# is adding lots of trendy new features doesn't mean you have to use them all, all the time.

Comment: Just keep in mind this doesn't actually disable the automatic model validation. The automatic model validation still occurs, it's just that nothing automatically happens when it fails.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and came across this solution:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/297568/how-to-suppress-suppressmodelstateinvalidfilter-at

My modified version which works for .NET 7 and lower:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;
    
public class SuppressModelStateInvalidFilterAttribute : Attribute, IActionModelConvention
{
    readonly string[] FilterTypeNames = new[] {
        "ModelStateInvalidFilter",
        "ModelStateInvalidFilterFactory"
    };

    public void Apply(ActionModel action)
    {

        for (var i = 0; i < action.Filters.Count; i++)
        {
            if (FilterTypeNames.Contains(action.Filters[i].GetType().Name))
            {
                action.Filters.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note, `ModelStateInvalidFilterFactory` is internal sealed class so you can't use it's Type directly.

Answer (score 1):

For disable this response in .net 6.0 and more.

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.16",
    "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "status": 415,
    "traceId": "00-650b34b60be38224db9e10ae617c8d59-25f7b2c33d509bfc-00"
}
```

Just use a nullable model in your service parameter and send your responses from catching error .

```
public IActionResult Register(MyModel? request)
{   
    using (IMyController controller = new MyController())
    {
        return Ok(controller.Perform(request));
    }
}
```

In controller:

```
public ResponseValue Perform(MyModel? request)
{
    if (request == null)
    {
        var result = new ResponseValue();            
        result.Code = 10040001;
        result.Status = "error";
        result.Description = "Manual validation error.";
        return result;
    }
```

If content request is null, the response is :

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "status": "error",
    "description": "Manual validation error."
}
```

Work fine for me..