# Disable auto model validation in ASP.NET Core 7 Web API?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, model-validation

I have a ASP.NET Core 7 Web API project with one action method. This action method accepts a model from request body like this:

```cs
public class ActionModel
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(3)]
    [RegularExpression("[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]*")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid ProfileId { get; set; }
}
```

Assume that this is my action method:

```
[HttpPost("extra-data")]
public async Task<ActionResult> MyAction([FromBody] ActionModel requestDto)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Try to do some thing");
    }

    _logger.LogError($"{ModelState.ErrorCount}");
    return Ok();
}
```

I expect that the execution goes through the action method body, but the request is validated by some other middleware before reaching the action method. How can I disable this default auto-validation middleware?

Comment: Do you want to disable model validation for all actions or specific action? For all actions: [Correct way to disable model validation in ASP.Net Core 2 MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46374994/8017690), for specific action: [Disable model validation for single .NET Core API action](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63181061/8017690)

Comment: If you send invalidated data to your endpoint, the request will not hit the endpoint but just return 400 directly, So you don't wanna this happen? I am not sure if I get your point.

Answer (score 3):

In your Startup.cs, maybe try to configure the ApiBehaviour:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
     {
         options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
     });
}
```